# Namecheap URL Redirect for all subpages?

Tags: redirects, url, namecheap

I have a Namecheap account for `mydomain.com`, which I would like to use to mask `uglydomain.com`.

I currently have URL Redirects (masked) set up for the @ and www hosts on the Advanced DNS settings of the Namecheap panel.

`mydomain.com` correctly shows the content from `uglydomain.com` while showing the former in the URL. However, clicking on the link to `uglydomain.com/page1.html` shows the correct content but still shows `mydomain.com` in the address bar, not `mydomain.com/page1.html`. Typing in `mydomain.com/page1.html` directly shows both the correct content and keeps `mydomain.com/page1.html` in the address bar.

Is there any way to redirect all subpages in this way, i.e. to not just show `mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Setup the domain with your web host as well that way both domains will load the same content. This can cause SEO duplicated content issues but if all you want to be able to do is access the site from different domains but the site work the same way then parking the new domain ontop of your current one will work.

If you are using cPanel add the new domain as a "Parked domain". If you are using apache then add the new domain as a `ServerAlias` to the virtualhost and point the domain to your server IP.

Comment: I am not using Namecheap hosting; the webpage is an academic one so it is hosted on a university website, I simply upload my html to a user folder and I'm not sure how much control I have. Do you have a reference that explains your solution in further detail?

Comment: What I mentioned would require you to edit the web server config to allow for requests to be made from your domain. Is the site accessible over direct IP? If so then you could still just point your domain to that IP and it should still function.